# What is the difference between "docker logs" and "docker attach"?

Tags: docker

They both allow you to connect to the *stdout/stderr* of a running container. In particular `docker logs --follow` seems to work similarly to `docker attach`.

Is one command an obsolete version of the other, or are there significant differences?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`docker logs` just pipes you *stderr/stdout*, while `docker attach` attaches *stdin/out/err* and *proxies signals*.

For example, the docs for [docker container attach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/#description) states

> You can detach from the container again (and leave it running) with CTRL-p CTRL-q (for a quiet exit), or CTRL-c which will send a SIGKILL to the container, or CTRL-\ to get a stacktrace of the Docker client when it quits. When you detach from the container's process the exit code will be returned to the client.

If the container has a pty I would assume you get attached to the pty and have full pty features (haven't tested that).

Hope this helps a bit!